iOS - WKWebView application Push Notification failed to navigate (Redirect) to the respective screen using deep linking
I am using WKWebView to load the URL for my hybrid web application. When I receive push notifications, I use deep linking to handle them by invoking the evaluateJavaScript function of WebView.
It should function as follows: when a push notification is tapped, it should take the user to the appropriate page (in the app) using the deep link URL. However, we occasionally notice that it is rerouting to the mobile app's home page or the page that was already accessed during the prior session or some random page of the app. In the issue case, we have noticed the error.
When I click the push notification it navigation should be to the direct designated screen not Home Screen.
Here I shared the code what I tried.
** // AppDelegate ** here I called the deeplink manager comman class for initial setup and return the url
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
DeepLinkManager.initialSetup(launchOptions: launchOptions) //Here I initialise the deep linking in app delegate when launch the app

window?.backgroundColor = .white
window?.tintColor = assetsAssets.colors.tintColor
return true}

public func application(
_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
return DeepLinkManager.handleDeepLink(app: app, open: url, options: options)}}

——> ViewController Class—— //This class I used for load the content in web view data and deep linking for redirect when receiving push notification
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

private var deepLinkObserver: Task<Void, Never>? {
willSet {
  deepLinkObserver?.cancel()
}}

private var webView: WKWebView!

private let processPool = WKProcessPool()


override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

  let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
  let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
  let userController = WKUserContentController()

  configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
  configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
  configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
  configuration.processPool = processPool
  configuration.websiteDataStore = dataStore
  configuration.userContentController = userController

  let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: 
  configuration)
  webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
  webview.allowsLinkPreview = false
  #if !PRODUCTION
     if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
       webview.isInspectable = true
     }
  #endif
     self.webView = webview

     let trampoline = Trampoline(delegate: self)
    for `case` in WebAppMessageName.allCases {
    let name = `case`.rawValue
    Self.logger.debug("subscribed for %@", name)
    userController.add(trampoline, name: name)
    }
  deepLinkObserver = Task {
      for await url in DeepLinkManager.shared.deepLinkStream {
          var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
          if components?.queryItems == nil {
              components?.queryItems = []
          }
          let magicNumberQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "magicNumber", value: "100")
          components?.queryItems?.append(magicNumberQueryItem)
          guard let modifiedUrl = components?.url?.absoluteString else { return }
          os_log("Attempting to navigate by deep link: %{public}@", log: ViewController.osLogger, type: .debug, modifiedUrl)
         do {
              let _ = try await webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.mobileNavigateByDeeplink('\(modifiedUrl)');true")
              os_log("Successfully navigated by deep link: %{public}@", log: ViewController.osLogger, type: .info, modifiedUrl) 
          } catch {
              os_log("Error navigating by deep link: %{public}@, error: %{public}@", log: ViewController.osLogger, type: .error, modifiedUrl, error.localizedDescription)
          }
      }
  }
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
webView.scrollView.bounces = false

guard let superview = view else {
  return
}
superview.backgroundColor = .white
superview.insertSubview(webview, belowSubview: loadShutter)
superview.addConstraints(
  [
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor),
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor),
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor),
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.rightAnchor)
  ]
)}

 deinit {
   notificationSubscriptions = nil
   deepLinkObserver = nil
   fallbackTask = nil
 }

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
notificationSubscriptions = [
  UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
  Notification.Name.BatchPushUserDidAnswerAuthorizationRequest
].map { name in
  Task { [weak self] in
    for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.observe(
      name: name,
      object: nil,
      queue: .main
    ) {
      guard let self = self else {
        break
      }
      self.getNotificationsStatus()
    }
  }
}}

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   getNotificationsStatus()
 }

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   notificationSubscriptions = nil
 }

 func load(url: URL, fallbackTimeout: Double) {
   webView.load(.init(url: url))
 }
 }

 extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

 func webView(
_ webView: WKWebView,
decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void
) {
guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
  decisionHandler(.allow)
  return
}
guard navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated, !excludedDomains.contains(url.host?.replacingOccurrences(of: "www.", with: "") ?? "") else {
  decisionHandler(.allow)
  return
}
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
decisionHandler(.cancel)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
Self.logger.debug("didFinish")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
Self.logger.error("error: %@", String(describing: error))
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
Self.logger.error("provisional navigation error: %@", String(describing: error))
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
self.webView.load(navigationAction.request)
return nil
}}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {

struct Attributes: Codable {
let isOptinEditor, isOptinOpta: Bool?
let userRegion: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case isOptinEditor = "is_optin_editor"
  case isOptin = "is_optin_"
  case userRegion = "user_region"
}}

struct Settings: Codable {
let region: String?
let apiRegion: String?
}

struct AppLink: Codable {
let appURLString: String
let installURLString: String
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case appURLString = "app_url"
  case installURLString = "install_url"
}
}

typealias TagsPayloadModel = PushNotificationManager.TagsPayloadModel

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
Self.logger.debug("postMessage name: %@, body: %@", message.name, String(describing: message.body))

if message.body as? String == Constants.WebMessage.articleTapped {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
  }
}


guard let body = message.body as? String else {
  return
}
guard let message = WebAppMessageName(rawValue: message.name) else {
  return
}

switch message {
case .tags:
  guard
    let data = body.data(using: .utf8),
    let tags = try? JSONDecoder().decode(
      [TagsPayloadModel].self,
      from: data
    )
  else {
    assertionFailure("Can not handle tags payload: \(body)")
    break
  }
  
  PersonalisationManager.shared.handle(tags)
  Task {
    do {
      PushNotificationManager.handle(
        tags,
        isHaveTeamWidgets: try await WidgetsManager.checkIfTeamsWidgetInstalled()
      )
    } catch  {
      Self.logger.error("check widgets installed error: %@", String(describing: error))
    }
  }
  
case .attributes:
  if let bodyData = body.data(using: .utf8) {
    PushNotificationManager.handle(data: bodyData)
    if let attributes = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Attributes.self, from: bodyData) {
      PushNotificationManager.set(attributes: attributes)
    }
  }
case .settings:
  if
    let bodyData = body.data(using: .utf8),
    let settings = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Settings.self, from: bodyData) {
    BISVersionManager.shared.set(settings: settings)
  }
  
case .statusBar:
  switch body.trimmingCharacters(in: .init([#"""#])) {
  case "dark":
    self.statusBarStyle = .darkContent
  case "light":
    self.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
  default:
    Self.logger.error("unknown status bar style %@", body)
    break
  }
  break
case .events:
  switch body {
  case "readyToShow":
    showContent()
  default:
    Self.logger.error("unknown event: %@", body)
    break
  }
case .notificationsPermissions:
  Task {
    do {
      try await PushNotificationManager.toggleNotifications(turnOn: true)
    } catch PushNotificationManager.Error.notificationsDenied {
      URL(
        string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
      ).map {
        UIApplication.shared.open($0)
      }
    }
  }
case .appLink:
  if
    let bodyData = body.data(using: .utf8),
    let appLink = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AppLink.self, from: bodyData) {
    if let appURL = URL(string: appLink.appURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(appURL)
    } else if let installURL = URL(string: appLink.installURLString) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(installURL)
    }
  }
  
}
}}

——> Common class for Deeplinking //This class I used for manage deep linking for redirecting from push notification
class DeepLinkManager {

static let logger = OSLog(category: "DeepLink")
static let shared = DeepLinkManager()

private let notifier = AsyncStreamNotifier<URL>()

var deepLink: URL? {
    didSet {
        Self.logger.debug("deep link: %@", deepLink?.absoluteString ?? "<nil>")
        if let deepLink = deepLink {
            notifier.update(value: deepLink)
        }
    }
}
var deepLinkStream: AsyncStream<URL> {
    notifier.makeAsyncStream()
}

static func initialSetup(launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
  var url: URL?
  if let urlString = ((launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any])?["com.batch"] as? [String: Any])?["l"] as? String {
      url = URL(string: urlString)
  } else if let urlPayload = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
      url = urlPayload
  }
  DeepLinkManager.shared.deepLink = url
 }

static func handleDeepLink(
app: UIApplication,
open url: URL,
options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]
) -> Bool {
  DeepLinkManager.shared.deepLink = url
return true
}}


WKErrorDomain: Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: window.mobileNavigateByDeeplink is not a function.

What might be the issue?
